# Non https downloads wp-header file on AWS EC2 Nginx, but SSL Works?

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, nginx

I am getting a very random issue. Whenever I access my site via http protocol, the wp-blog-header.php file gets downloaded, or I simply get a 502 error from cloudflare (which I am using). That file says the following:

```
<?php
/**
* Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
* wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
*
* @package WordPress
*/

/**
* Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
*
* @var bool
*/
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

I am not getting this issue when I access the site via https protocol.

The site is: https://somersetbaby.com

I have the following in place in my wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_HOME','https://somersetbaby.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://somersetbaby.com');
```

and the following is my nginx configuration file for the site:

```
    server {

    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl     on;
    ssl_certificate         /not/here/somersetbaby.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /not/here/somersetbaby.key;

server_name somersetbaby.com   www.somersetbaby.com;


access_log /var/log/nginx/somersetbaby.com.access.log rt_cache;
error_log /var/log/nginx/somersetbaby.com.error.log;


root /var/www/somersetbaby.com/htdocs;



index index.php index.html index.htm;


include common/wpfc-php7.conf;

include common/wpcommon-php7.conf;
include common/locations-php7.conf;
    include /var/www/somersetbaby.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;
```

I also have a default file, but if I delete it, I get a 521 error and the site will reload endlessly and if I include it, I cant get the site to force SSL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its because the way wordpress detects HTTPS, a cheap hack is to place the following in `wp-config.php`

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') { 
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

Comment: Works for Wordpress behind `Cloudflare -> Load Balancer -> NGINX -> LXC Container` type setup also.

Comment: I placed this into the wp-config file, I restarted nginx, and I purged my cache from cloudflare. Still having the same issue.

I am also not using a load balancer on AWS, this was a simple install of an Ubuntu Instance and easyengine wordpress installation (with FastCGI and PHP7).

Comment: im getting 502 bad gateway for HTTP, in your changes is nginx still listening on port 80, https://community.lxc.systems/t/deploy-wordpress-in-a-lxc-container-on-a-fresh-vps-served-over-ssl-with-lets-encrypt-setup-and-ready-in-8-about-minutes/18

Comment: If I add to listen to port 80 in the nginx conf file, I get a 400 error. If I take it out, I am getting the 502 error. I have placed the code you mentioned above in the wp-config file and it is still there.

This is tough one, because It shouldnt be happening (logically)

Answer (score 0):

I did get it to work, I had to look at another server setup I had that was working.

I created a file called /etc/nginx/conf.d/force-ssl-somersetbaby.com.conf

Then it had the following code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.somersetbaby.com somersetbaby.com;
    return 301 https://somersetbaby.com$request_uri;
}
```

That seemed to do the trick. I have restarted the server and purged my caches.

Thank you for all your help.